# How to measure Peak signal to noise ratio of images?

Tags: image, image-processing, filter

I have the following images :

[image]

Corrupted with 30% salt and pepper noise

[image]

After denoising

I have denoised images with various techniques

How do i compare which method is the best in terms of denoising

```
    function PSNR = PeakSignaltoNoiseRatio(origImg, distImg)

origImg = double(origImg);
distImg = double(distImg);

[M N] = size(origImg);
error = origImg - distImg;
MSE = sum(sum(error .* error)) / (M * N);

if(MSE > 0)
    PSNR = 10*log(255*255/MSE) / log(10);
else
    PSNR = 99;
end
```

which two images should i take to calculate the PSNR?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you check the [Wikipedia article on PSNR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peak_signal-to-noise_ratio)? For one, it gives a cleaner formula that would fix up your code (for example, why are you checking whether MSE > 0? If you defined MSE right, it has to be greater than 0. Also, this looks to be Matlab code, so use the `log10()` function to save some confusing base conversions. Lastly, be sure that the input to this function is actually a quantized image on the 0-255 scale, and not a double-valued image between 0 and 1).

Your question is unclear. If you want to use PSNR as a metric for performance, then you should compute the PSNR of each denoised method against the original and report those numbers. That probably won't give a very good summary of which methods are doing better, but it's a start. Another method could be to hand-select smaller sub-regions of the original image that you think correspond to different qualitative phenomena, such as a window on the background, a window on the foreground, and a window spanning the two. Then compute the PSNR for only those windows, again repeated for each denoised result vs. the original. In the end, you want a table showing PSNR of each different method as compared to the original, possibly with this sub-window breakdown.

You may want to look into more sophisticated methods depending on what application this is for. The chapter on total variation image denoising in Tony Chan's book is very helpful ( [link](http://www.amazon.com/Image-Processing-Analysis-Variational-Stochastic/dp/sitb-next/089871589X) ).

Comment: Yes i did check wikipedia , I know PSNR is measured comparing the original vs Distorted image however how does one calculate the PSNR if we donot know what are original is we only have a noisy image and a corresponding denoised image with say a filtering method ? Normally reserch papers compare different denoising techniques they use PSNR to act as a quality measure how do they do that?

Comment: yes i did the same before comparing denoised image with the original image but got wrong results i had a more noisy image giving a higher PSNR value which should be the opposite way

Answer (score 0):

Here is Jython/Python example using DataMelt program.
Put these lines into a file "test.py" and run inside the DataMelt.
It will print PSNR value for 2 downloaded images. Replace the files names if you have different images.

```
from Catalano.Imaging.Tools import ObjectiveFidelity
from Catalano.Imaging  import FastBitmap
from jhplot import *
print Web.get("http://jwork.org/dmelt/examples/data/logo_jhepwork.png")
print Web.get("http://jwork.org/dmelt/examples/data/logo_jhepwork_noisy.png")
original=FastBitmap("logo_jhepwork.png")
original.toGrayscale()
reconstructed=FastBitmap("logo_jhepwork_noisy.png")
reconstructed.toGrayscale()
img=ObjectiveFidelity(original,reconstructed)
print "Peak signal-to-noise ratio (PSNR)=",img.getPSNR()
```